# Is there any method to set a constant number of contour points for different images?

Tags: python, opencv

Iam working on a project where I need a constant set of contour / land mark points. My input image is different types of clothes. And using x,y points i need to find out whether it is elbow points or shoulder points.. Can anyone suggest a method for this?
Because I checked using contour detection , model classification of clothes. In contour iam getting different set of contour points for different clothes.
For example, If I can findout contour[0] is elbow point ,then contour[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZiVy.jpg) is shoulder point, I can do my algorithm very easily..I will attach some examples of my input with its points

[image: Input example 1]

[[[ 20 155]] [[ 88 239]] [[134 215]] [[146 327]] [[135 452]] [[361 451]] [[367 207]] [[418 233]] [[475 176]] [[472 160]] [[382  80]] [[301  55]] [[283  79]] [[255  86]] [[219  77]] [[201  51]] [[169  73]] [[120  83]]]

[image: Input example 2]

[[[352  36]] [[268   7]] [[259  25]] [[221  33]] [[185  24]] [[176   8]] [[ 91  35]] [[ 65  57]] [[ 13 170]] [[ 64 204]] [[100 201]] [[108 303]] [[ 84 471]] [[139 492]] [[273 493]] [[330 484]] [[354 467]] [[335 297]] [[341 193]] [[374 208]] [[425 174]] [[373  58]]]

In first image contour count is 18 and in second contour count is 22 and for both starting point of contour is different.
Is there any way to findout the position of dress with its points?

#####################################UPDATE2#################################

Annotations I created for training using https://imglab.in/#

[image: Annotated Image]

Test result,
[image]

Comment: Which points would be elbow points, and which points shoulder points in this example? You could probably look at the angle that 3 points make, or look at the location of a point to deduce if it is an elbow or shoulder point.

Answer (score 1):

The `dlib's shape predictor` should work for you. Train it for your images and it will give you a constant-size, ordered set of points.

For how to train it, Have a look at this [Pyimagesearch tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/16/training-a-custom-dlib-shape-predictor/).

Comment: Thanks! Will it work for different static images,if i have a large dataset trained? @Baraa

Comment: @sharonsamson Yes, this shape predictor model is very robust if trained correctly. This of course assumes that you have your images cropped in a similar fashion (look at the original usecase: face detector -> bounding box -> cropped face image -> shape predictor for facial landmarks).

Please do not forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Iam working on the model. I trained it well,but during testing there is a line ,detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector(). What should I give instead of this? because my input is clothes. @Baraa

Comment: I mentioned this in the earlier comment, in the case of face shape predictor, the face bounding box should be located first. If in your case, the clothes images are cropped then you can just ignore the line that you've mentioned and use the full image as an input to your shape model.

Comment: Is it possible to  put the modified testing code here?

Comment: Please show your effort, maybe post another question if you have issues implementing it.

Comment: I created one svm detector and got the landmark points,But the output is not as expected. I will update the question.Please take a look! If you have any suggestions let me know @Baraa